# Convolution of trigonometric polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

Given that $f,g$ are trigonometric polynomial of this form $a_0 + \sum \limits_{n=1}^N a_n \sin( 2 \pi n x)+ b_n \cos(2 \pi n x)$,

Prove that $f*g (x) = \int \limits_{0}^{1} f(x-t) g(t)\,dt$ is also trigonometric polynomial

My proof :  from the linearity of the integral and the trigonometric polynomials, its suffice to prove that $ a*b , a*\sin(2 \pi n x) , a*\cos(2 \pi n x) , \sin(2 \pi k x)* \sin (2 \pi n x) , \cos(2 \pi k x) * \cos(2 \pi n x) , \sin(2 \pi k x) * \cos(2 \pi n x)$ are trigonometric polynomials .

I have 2 questions , is this proof correct ?

and also what is $\sin(2 \pi k x) * \cos(2 \pi n x)$ ?

Note : $a,b$ are real numbers and $k,n$ are positive integers.

Comment: Your proof seems correct and you can use $\sin(a) \cos(b)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b) \right)$ to compute explicitly the convolution.

Comment: Is the subtraction supposed to be modulo $1\text{?} \qquad$